# Django Filtering Admin Dropdowns

Tags: django, filtering, admin

It seems this questions has been answered many times, but I am new to Django and apparently missing something when I try to work through the answers I have been finding.  I have 2 Models, Model A is the main one and has a foreign key to Model B.  When I make a new Model A in the Django Admin, I want the drop down for picking a Model B to only show the Model B's that have not already been assigned to a Model A.  Can anyone point the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [provide a custom form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) to the admin, telling it to [only show a certain queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for the Model B field:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Person

class ModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):

    model_b = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ModelB.objects.exclude(model_a__isnull=False))

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA

class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModelAForm
```